# ObjectDisposedException generates when the list item's parent is not active

Tags: list, unity-game-engine, while-loop, coroutine, vuforia

I am using vuforia. OnTargetFound the parent object will be setActive true, a list will be populated with reference of its children, a will start holding the process of some calculations in while loop and OnTargetLost the process will end with stopCoroutine and the list will be cleared and the parent object will be set inactive. Through the process the list is being accessed.

The issue is that even if the target is lost the coroutine will complete itself and then will be stopped. but before that the parent object is being inactive and the process is accessing the list items,
"***ObjectDisposedException: SerializedProperty repeatList.Array.data[0] has disappeared!***"
this error is generating.

How can I get rid of this issue??
the process must be in loop as the marker is tracked.

I have tried:
1.using waitForSecond in coroutine
2.using break statement(but its the process is long so have no idea where to break)
3.try and catch
4.using flag and conditions
5.invokeRepeating
6.using array instead of list
7.setting order of execution
8.using delegate, action, event
9.async await

Here is the code:

```
private IEnumerator DoCalculation()
    {
        while (doCalculation)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.8f);
            yield return StartCoroutine(Calculation());
        }
    }

private IEnumerator Calculation()
    {
       if (!AreAllOptionsTracked())
        {
            answerImg.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            if (model != null)
            {
                model.SetActive(false);
            }
            yield break;
        }

        isCalculationOn = true;
        if (answerObj != null && answerObj.activeInHierarchy)
        {
            SetRepeatPos();
        }
        bool isCorrect = CheckOptionOrder();
        isCalculationOn = false;   
    }

private void ClearGame()
    {
        doCalculation = false;
        isCalculationOn = false;
        StartCoroutine(ClearAll());
    }

private IEnumerator ClearAll()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
        if (isCalculationOn)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.7f);
        }
        if (!isCalculationOn && answerObj != null)
        {
            answerObj.SetActive(false);
            answerObj = null;
        }
        repeatList.Clear();
    }
```

Here the "answerObj" is that parent object and "repeatList" is the list of its children. "SetRepeatPos()" is using the list items

Comment: Could you show the according code?

Comment: Sounds like some Inspector / EditorWindow issue

Comment: Hey @derHugo, I have updated my question with code. please check it.

Comment: as I said this error seems to rather be something related to the Inspector of your component and how it tries to draw the items of `repeatList` in the Inspector ... a Coroutine should actually be "paused" if the according object goes inactive

Comment: That's the thing, the coroutine is not getting paused or stopped. Instead it is completing the code and then it is not repeating if the condition is false.

Comment: that would mean the object being deactivated is not the one running the coroutine right? unfortunately it is pretty hard to reproduce    / understand the actual issue - in the code alone I don't see an issue that would be causing this

Comment: in general there are quite some routines in your code .. but where is the whole process actually kicked off? Is it possible that multiple routines run parallel?

Comment: Yes, it is hard to understand the origin point of the error. there no reference of the code from where the the error is generating. For that i have tried and tested adding some break points and conditions where i think the error is from. but couldn't get it.

Comment: Is there any other way than the coroutine i could use here? Ways other than i have mentioned.